# Why does the order of useState elements matter in React?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, state

So I was doing a dummy quiz test app using React.js following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lya-qYiDqIA&t=5s&ab_channel=ChrisBlakely) tutorial when I came across an error that happened because the order of the declared state elements was slightly different.

[This is the final state of the app.](https://github.com/chrisblakely01/quiz-app/blob/master/final/src/App.js)

All I did differently was that I switched line 44 with line 45, and my code broke completely. Why would the useState order matter that much? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

TL/DR react wraps your function component with a module that holds the snapshots of your state in an array of states.
each useState (or hook) gets its own ordinal index by the order it is called with in your component.
each component re render this array is addressed by the ordinal index of the useState to get the current state.

and this is how the state is maintained between rerenders.

btw,
if useState would have accept a unique key, the react wouldnt be such sensative to useState call order. and could use a map rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

please read this, should make everything more clear:

[Explanation](https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/)

If that is to long check the official [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

//Edit to clarify:

That is just the way react assigns pieces of state to the correct hook, through call order.

Let's say you have a factory where you have workers that always do step 1 then step 2 then step 3.

React works the same way:

Hook 1 belongs to state 1

Hook 2 belongs to state 2

Hook 3 belongs to state 3

If you now call Hook 2 before Hook 1, react will mix together Hook 2 with state 1 which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: sorry, i still don't get it

Comment: I clarified above.